Pandas conditional filtering on categorical values
I have the following table in pandas:



Index
Ingredient
Dish




1
Potato
Pie


2
Potato
Juice


3
Potato
Fries


4
Potato
Pure


5
Apple
Pie


6
Apple
Juice


7
Apple
Fries


8
Apple
Pure



and want to apply the following filter:
If Ingredient=='Apple' then only keep Dish=['Pie','Juice']
The result should look like this:



Index
Ingredient
Dish




1
Potato
Pie


2
Potato
Juice


3
Potato
Fries


4
Potato
Pure


5
Apple
Pie


6
Apple
Juice



How can I do that?

Whats happens if only one value from ['Pie','Juice'] match?

That's fine. Only Pie and Juice from Dish should be kept, if Ingredient =Apple

You want:

to keep any row that does not equal 'Apple' ('Ingredient'), via Series.ne.
or (|) keep any row that is in ['Pie', 'Juice'] ('Dish'), via Series.isin.

m = df['Ingredient'].ne('Apple')
n = df['Dish'].isin(['Pie', 'Juice'])
df[m | n]

Output:
   Index Ingredient   Dish
0      1     Potato    Pie
1      2     Potato  Juice
2      3     Potato  Fries
3      4     Potato   Pure
4      5      Apple    Pie
5      6      Apple  Juice

Logic:
df.assign(**{'m': m, 
             'n': n, 
             'm | n': m | n
             }
          )

   Index Ingredient   Dish      m      n  m | n
0      1     Potato    Pie   True   True   True
1      2     Potato  Juice   True   True   True
2      3     Potato  Fries   True  False   True
3      4     Potato   Pure   True  False   True
4      5      Apple    Pie  False   True   True
5      6      Apple  Juice  False   True   True
6      7      Apple  Fries  False  False  False
7      8      Apple   Pure  False  False  False

# also possible: 'any': lambda x: x[['m', 'n']].any(axis=1)


That works! Thanks for the comprehensive explanation!

You can select values with Apple if not match list and then invert mask by ~ for expected ouput:
out = df[ ~(df['Ingredient'].eq('Apple') & ~df['Dish'].isin(['Pie','Juice']))]

print (out)
   Index Ingredient   Dish
0      1     Potato    Pie
1      2     Potato  Juice
2      3     Potato  Fries
3      4     Potato   Pure
4      5      Apple    Pie
5      6      Apple  Juice

How it working:
print (df.assign(m1=df['Ingredient'].eq('Apple'),
                 m2 = ~df['Dish'].isin(['Pie','Juice']),
                 both =(df['Ingredient'].eq('Apple') & ~df['Dish'].isin(['Pie','Juice'])),
                 invert= ~(df['Ingredient'].eq('Apple') & ~df['Dish'].isin(['Pie','Juice']))))
   Index Ingredient   Dish     m1     m2   both  invert
0      1     Potato    Pie  False  False  False    True
1      2     Potato  Juice  False  False  False    True
2      3     Potato  Fries  False   True  False    True
3      4     Potato   Pure  False   True  False    True
4      5      Apple    Pie   True  False  False    True
5      6      Apple  Juice   True  False  False    True
6      7      Apple  Fries   True   True   True   False
7      8      Apple   Pure   True   True   True   False


That works! Thanks for the comprehensive explanation!
